# pandas sort values of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

I have a set of data about football:

[image: dataset]

I sorted it by how many matches were played at each ground:

```py
fb2 = fb.groupby(by=['Ground'])['Ground'].count()
print(fb2)
```

Output:

```
Ground
Aberdeen         11
Abu Dhabi        37
Adelaide         82
Ahmedabad        24
Albion            5
                 ..
Vijayawada        1
Visakhapatnam    11
Wellington       56
Whangarei         1
Worcester         3
Name: Ground, Length: 173, dtype: int64
```

Now I want to sort the results, in descending order of how many matches were played at each ground.

I am very new to python...any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use named aggregation, you can specify a column name to sort on:

```
fb2 = (
  fb
  .groupby('Ground', as_index=False)
  .agg(n_matches=('Ground', 'count'))
  .sort_values('n_matches', ascending=False)
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

The type of `fb.groupby(by=['Ground'])['Ground'].count()` is Series, you can sort it using [pandas.Series.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html)

```py
fb.groupby(by=['Ground'])['Ground'].count().sort_values(ascending=False))
```